# How does Carapace Armor look with genetic manipulations?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

As soon as you use MELD to manipulate a soldier genetically, he gets new armor. All of the new armor-decos are sleeveless. How does it look when I equip a genetically manipulated soldier with carpace armor? Will it also become sleeveless or does it more look like the normal one?

Comment: On a side note, there's a mod to "correct" that and allow you to visually identify armor types easily: [revenge of the sleeves](http://www.nexusmods.com/xcom/mods/411/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Carapace Armour will become sleeveless on genetically manipulated units.

[image: sleeveless carapace]

Comment: Hey, thank you for the answer and also for the effort of taking a screenshot!!! :-)

Comment: When customised you get a choice of different shoulder and elbow protection. As shown on my heavy & sniper on the left, http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=196761582

Comment: More generally, all the armors have the sleeveless look on genetically modified soldiers.

Comment: I actually find it quite hard the tell the armours apart on the battlefield when they're restyled for gene-modded soldiers. Except arcangel.